# import sql data into excel using vba

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm trying to pull data from SQL table into excel. I've recorded a macro doing so using the data source tool.  However the amount of data I'm pulling generally crashes excel.  Is there a way to add a variable in my vba script to limit the data pulled from the sql table?  Essentially adding a where clause to a select statement in sql.

Thanks!

-Sean

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=10.22.30.215;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Aut" _
    , _
    "o Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID="FakeName";Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=Fa" _
    , "lse;Initial Catalog=FakeCatelog"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")). _
    QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
    """FakeName""")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceConnectionFile = _
    "C:\UFakeFilePathodc"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "FakeName"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 3):

Try connecting to the database and doing a query instead of trying to pull the entire database into your sheet.  This should get you started:
Make sure to add the ""Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library" Reference or run this line once:
`ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{B691E011-1797-432E-907A-4D8C69339129}", 6, 0`

```
Sub QueryDB()
    Dim dbName As ADODB.Connection
    Dim dbResults As ADODB.Recordset
    Set dbName = openDBConn("YOURDATABASE", "YourTable")
    Set dbResults = dbName.Execute("SELECT * FROM YOURDATABASE")
    While Not dbResults.EOF
        'Do Something'
        dbResults.MoveNext
    Wend
End Sub

Function openDBConn(dataSource As String, table As String) As ADODB.Connection
    Dim newDBConn As ADODB.Connection
    Set newDBConn = New ADODB.Connection
    newDBConn.CommandTimeout = 60
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=" & dataSource & ";INITIAL CATALOG=" & table & ";INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI"
    newDBConn.Open strConn
    Set openDBConn = newDBConn
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @whytheq - instructions on the Reference added

Comment: @KevinPope - that line of code that adds the reference; where do I find out more about that?

Comment: @whytheq - Honestly, I learned about it on [this thread](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=22483).  It's useful for just passing around a `.bas` file and not having to give detailed instructions on how to add references to non-tech-savvy users.  It doesn't work in Outlook, but in other Office apps you can enable it in the Macro Settings in the Trust Center.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are happy with the code it might be worth switching it to `late binding`. `Early binding` is good as you get full intellisense when developing the application but I find late binding to be a little less troublesome as time goes by and applications get upgraded to new versions.

Also as I use the connection strings quite a lot it can be good to have it decalred at the top of your module ...saves digging around for this hard code in the future:

*(p.s. this is just Kevin's code with a couple of changes; not necessarily improvements but more just alternatives)*

```
Global Const strConn As String = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=" & dataSource & ";INITIAL CATALOG=" & table & ";INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI"
Sub QueryDB()
       Dim dbName As Object
       Dim dbResults As Object
       Set dbName = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
       dbName = openDBConn("YOURDATABASE", "YourTable")
       Set dbResults = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
       dbResults = dbName.Execute("SELECT * FROM YOURDATABASE")
       While Not dbResults.EOF
           'Do Something'
           dbResults.MoveNext
       Wend
End Sub

Function openDBConn(dataSource As String, table As String) As ADODB.Connection
       Dim newDBConn As Object
       Set newDBConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
       newDBConn.CommandTimeout = 60

       newDBConn.Open strConn
       Set openDBConn = newDBConn
End Function
```